# Embed external HTML page inside AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, apache-zeppelin

Is it possible to embed an external HTML page inside of AngularJS?  For instance if i have a page at "localhost:8080/mypage/5533n", is there an easy way to embed inside my angular app?

I have a graph/table that I want to display, but i keep hitting Lexer errors, and sometimes CORS problems which I already fixed.  I'm using the below code:

```
 <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="http://localhost:8080/#/notebook/2APHT5YD2/paragraph/20150609-170553_989764970?asIframe"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing `'` here for your `ng-include` URL.

```
ng-include="'http://localhost:8080/#/notebook/2APHT5YD2/paragraph/20150609-170553_989764970?asIframe'"
```